# SQL select TOP records partition by couples of column from multiple columns

Tags: sql, group-by, partition

What i want to get is all the `customer` which total cost is TOP2, with all the properties are needed.),

The question is SQL used is too complicated, If there's a way to simplipy it?

The date `table` & my `SQL` is something like below:

| area | customer | property | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| area1 | cus1 | property11 | cost11 |
| area1 | cus1 | property12 | cost12 |
| area1 | cus2 | property21 | cost21 |

```
SELECT
    area,
    customer,
    property,
    SUM(cost) AS cost
FROM
    table
WHERE
    customer IN
             (SELECT
                  f.customer
             FROM
                 (SELECT
                      p.area,
                      p.customer,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY area ORDER BY cost) AS number,
                      p.cost
                 FROM
                    (SELECT
                          area,
                          costomer,
                          SUM(cost) AS cost
                     FROM
                         table
                     GROUP BY
                         costomer
                     )a
                 WHERE number <=2
                 )aa
             )aaa
GROUP BY
    area,
    customer,
    property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function (or `RANK()` if you want ties included):

```
select t.area, t.customer, t.properties, t.cost
from (
  select area, customer, collect_set(property) properties, sum(cost) cost, 
    row_number() over (partition by area order by sum(cost) desc) rn
  from tablename
  group by area, customer
) t
where t.rn <= 2
```

Comment: thx for you answer. You mean, i've already solved the problem in first `WHERE` sdatement? oh my~

Comment: You were almost there. You don't need all these nested subqueries provided that your database supports aggregate functions inside window functions.

Comment: There is third COLUMN `property` in the outer SELECT statement. How to deal with it?

Comment: Which property value do you want in the results? There may be more than 1 value for each combination of area and customer. This is why it is not included in the results.

Comment: For example in your sample data if area1, cus1 is in the results which property should also be in the results? porperty11 or porperty12?

Comment: all the property `porperty11` & `porperty12` should be included in the result. Is there a way to go?

Comment: What is your database that you use? (MySql, Oracle, SQL Serever ...)

Comment: You can use collect_set() to get all the properties as a comma separated list. See my edited answer.

Comment: There is also collect_list instead of collect_set if you want duplicate properties in the results.